# JwtToken cannot be sent - Microsoft Azure Bot - LUIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to start programming Bots for Skype, Slack etc.
I have setup a Bot in the Microsoft Azure Portal and enabled continuous deployment with Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Visual Studio (VS).
Which I just used to get the code from Azure to my computer but want to use in the future to deploy as well.

When I run the stock Bot from Azure locally in VS, with only the LUISAppId and APIKey filled in, it fails when I send a message to it.

This is the error code:

```
iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 : Service url localhost:59706 is not trusted and JwtToken cannot be sent to it.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
I already tried:
`MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"localhost");`
and `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"localhost:59706");`
in `MessageController.cs`

Comment: Can you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the error that prevented me from successfully talking to the bot was something different and got resolved by using a proxy.

The above console log though still exists:

```
iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 : Service url localhost:59706 is not trusted and JwtToken cannot be sent to it
```