# Remote name could not be resolved 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com' - Microsoft Azure Bot - QnAMaker

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have a Microsoft Azure Bot running with basic QnA Dialog implementation.
When I run the stock code from Azure, with only the `QnAKnowledgebaseId`and `QnASubscriptionKey` inserted, it will give me the following error (not anymore - see **EDIT**):

```
Exception: The remote name could not be resolved: ‘westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com’
```

In addition to this error, there is another console output in Virtual Studio:

```
iisexpress.exe Warning: 0 : Service url localhost:59706 is not trusted and JwtToken cannot be sent to it.
```

This issue is probably related to [JwtToken cannot be sent - Microsoft Azure Bot - LUIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768847/jwttoken-cannot-be-sent-microsoft-azure-bot-luis)

Does anyone have the same issue and knows a solution?

---

### EDIT

I now used a proxy to connect to the network on my computer.
The Expection doesn't appear anymore but now another one appears:

`Exception: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

the Warning though still exists.

Comment: So you are running the code in Azure but using localhost?

Comment: I am running the code locally, but go the code from Azure. So right now I am not deploying anything but only running the bot locally

Comment: Did you build the bot application on Azure via Azure bot Service, and then copy the code from Azure to local, test and debug on local? If so, what is the `host plan` you chose when you were building the bot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for ages.

Adding this to the web.config fixed it for me.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```